# Dovecot - Fatal: execv(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login) failed: Permission denied

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I'm in the process of trying to set my own mail server reasonably closely following this guide: 
http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsa-proof-your-e-mail-in-2-hours/

I've just started to test the configuration and I can't seem to get an ssl connection.

When I run this command:

`openssl s_client -prexit -state -debug -connect localhost:993`

It says the "SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 298 bytes", examining /var/log/dovecot.log reveals:

> Fatal: execv(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login) failed: Permission denied

Which is odd because `ls -lL /usr/lib/dovecot | grep imap-login` renders:

> drwxrwxrwx 2 mail dovecot    4096 Jul  8 12:25 imap-login

and http://wiki.dovecot.org/UserIds seems to indicate that those permisions should be sufficient.

Since I really don't have any idea what's going on here is `dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.1.7: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.0.4-x86_64-linode57 x86_64 Debian 7.8 
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 0
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/decrypted-mail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = mail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = mail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  user = mail
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=mail gid=mail home=/decrypted-mail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
userdb {
  args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
  driver = static
}
```

What have I got wrong?

Comment: please post the full output of `ls -la /usr/lib/dovecot`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GRrkevhh

Comment: Do  `/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem` and `/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem` exist?!

Comment: Yes, both /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem and /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem exist.
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1704 Jul  8 12:07 /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem`
and
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1245 Jul  8 12:07 /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem`

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have configured the port for IMAPs.

```
service imap-login {
   inet_listener imap {
   port = 0
   }
   inet_listener imaps {
   port = 993
   ssl = yes
   }
}
```

If you enter `netstat -tulpen` you should now see a line like

```
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:993   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   0     5728257  23418/dovecot
```

Now the server will be listen on Port 993.

Comment: I think you probably caught a really valid mistake, but that doesn't seem to be changing any of the behaviour outlined above. I made the change though, and netstat shows what it should.

Comment: So I think it´s better for you to start up with a clean install and try to get dovecot running - later add the features you want. For example: The owner of /usr/lib/dovecot doesn´t fit to mine (I´m using Debian Jessie) - are you shure this is right?!

Answer (score 0):

An AppArmor problem for me.

This is not a problem with Dovecot or permissions at all, also you could have all the permissions and still receive this error.

The problem was with new kernel module AppArmor, at least for me. I received a "Fatal: execv(/usr/libexec/dovecot/log) failed: Permission denied)", when try to start Dovecot.

To fix this

We must add the following lines to file **/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.dovecot**:

```
/var/log/dovecot rw,
/var/log/dovecot/error.log rw,
/var/log/dovecot/info.log rw,
/var/log/dovecot/debug.log rw,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/managesieve Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/log Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/anvil Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/config Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/stats Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/imap-login Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/auth Puxmr,
/usr/libexec/dovecot/imap Puxmr,
/etc/letsencrypt/live/artemisa.soft-gator.com/fullchain.pem r,
/etc/letsencrypt/live/artemisa.soft-gator.com/privkey.pem r,
network,
```

We must be sure to have the log files already created. Also, it is very helpful see logs under /var/log/messages.